# Пишется ли "новый курс" с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, кавычки, названия

Собственно, весь вопрос исчерпан темой: следует ли писать выражение "Новый курс" (имеется в виду политика Рузвельта) с прописной буквы и в кавычках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет Википедия:

> «Но́вый курс» (англ. New Deal) — название экономической политики, проводимой администрацией Франклина Делано Рузвельта начиная с 1933 года с целью выхода из масштабного экономического кризиса (Великая депрессия), охватившего США с 1929 по 1933.

Обратите внимание: это название, а следовательно с прописной и в кавычках. Вот что пишет Грамота:

> [Вопрос № 272944](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=272944)
>   Здравствуйте ещё раз,
>   помогите, пожалуйста, согласовать, сказуемое с подлежащим(и):
>   «Новый курс» президента Рузвельта, в частности, закупки для поддержания цен на сельскохозяйственную продукцию, сыграл(и) огромное значение в восстановлении экономики штата.
>   Заранее спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Корректно: **«Новый курс» президента Рузвельта**, в частности закупки для поддержания цен на сельскохозяйственную продукцию, сыграл огромную роль в восстановлении экономики штата.

РИА:

> заложивших основу "Нового курса". (["Новый курс" Франклина Делано Рузвельта. Справка](https://ria.ru/economy/20081209/156850733.html))

То же в в Большой [Советской Энциклопедии](http://bse.sci-lib.com/article082376.html).

Нужно признать, что в Нацкорпусе наблюдается по этому поводу разнобой (все возможные варианты написания присутствуют), но есть и то, что совпадает с "генеральной линией":

> Для американских масс-медиа «борьба с терроризмом» ― это длящаяся уже второй год общенациональная кампания, своего рода аналог **«Нового курса»** Франклина Рузвельта или участия США во Второй мировой войне, которое когда-то тоже преподносилось американскому обывателю чрезвычайно «кампанейски». [Ярослав Шимов. Аквариум // «Отечественные записки», 2003]

Comment: Ну, Википедии вряд ли стоит очень доверять. А что касается Грамоты, то я  видел этот ответ, но в нем "Новый курс" — в начале предложения, поэтому не очень понятно, с чем связана прописная буква — с началом предложения или с тем, что выражение пишется с прописной.

Comment: А к БСЭ как Вы относитесь?

Answer (score 1):

В одной и той же статье можно встретить разное написание, и это нормально. Есть официальное название "Новый курс" (это имя собственное) и есть его нарицательный неофициальный аналог новый курс/новый курс Рузвельта.

http://fb.ru/article/43557/novyiy-kurs-ruzvelta-i-ego-mesto-v-istorii

Новый курс Рузвельта и его место в истории

В отличие от предшественников, он придерживался довольно левых взглядов и считал, что государство должно активно вмешиваться в экономические процессы и помогать своим гражданам справиться с кризисом, а не ждать, пока экономика «придет в себя». Эти убеждения нашли отражение в его реформах, известных как **новый курс Рузвельта**.

Итоги

Итак, что же дал **«Новый курс»** американской экономике? К сожалению, принятые реформы не смогли предотвратить новый кризис, разразившийся в 1937 г.